# How can I identify all these items?

Tags: might-and-magic-x-legacy

I'm only a little bit into the game. I'm playing in Warrior Mode (the harder of the two difficulties) and I've completed the Spider Lair and have now left town seeking new adventures. My party is about halfway to level 3 and I've got 6 unidentified items.

So far, the only method I've discovered to identify items was the lady at the magic shop in town, who will identify items for 300 gold. Since I've only earned about 1600 gold up to this point in the game, most of which went to spell purchases, I only had enough money to identify one of the 6 items, which turned out to be fairly worthless and won't even sell for the identify cost.

It looks like in a few levels I can get an identify spell (assuming I can find a place to buy it) when I become an Expert in primordial magic, but are there any other ways to get my items identified? Right now gold seems like too precious a resource to blow it on item identification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like getting the primordial magic identify spell is your best bet.

From a thread on [somethingawful](http://forums.somethingawful.com/showthread.php?threadid=3605196)

> Early Game Tips
>
> [...]
>
> Have one character reach Expert in Primordial magic with their first few level ups to unlock the Identify spell. Otherwise you will be paying out the rear end to identify stuff in the beginning.
>
> [...]

The trainer that can teach you the spell is located in the wagon labelled "Itinerant Merchant", North of Sorpigal when you head towards the castle.